# Changing a form's action attribute in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set a hash value in a form's action, to keep it when the form is submitted.

Firefox allows me to update the hash and redirects accordingly, but IE doesn't. I initially thought this was related to IE not allowing hash values in the action attribute at all, but it seems I can't dynamically set the action at all in IE - with a hash or not? Is that right?

I'm using the following jQuery:

`$("#options-form").attr('action', '#' + hash);`

To update:

`<form id="options-form" action="" method="get">`

(On a sidenote, this wasn't needed in Firefox, because FF appears to preserve the current hash if it was only the GET params that changed.)

Comment: Just guessing here: what happens when you give the form the name. "options_form" (underscore instead of dash)?

Comment: Is using the # symbol in the action appropriate when it is normally used in a url for navigating to a named anchor within the page?

Comment: @Pointy: That didn't help. Plus, that's not the issue. Even if I manually set the action's value using IE's dev tools (either in the console or in the attribute tab), I still don't get redirected to the new address (but I do in FF). @Dave: Yeah, I guess you're right, it is indeed bending the intended use. I guess that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a querystring parameter to pass a certain value to the form action page?

i.e. `<form id="options-form" action="mydestination.html?specialvarname=specialvalue" method="get">`

That way you can easily fetch the variable on the destination page and you don't violate or misuse anything... ?